# Mongoose Populate Null Reference

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have two simple models defined in Mongoose, composed of two schema Client and City, I have the property city defined in Client as a ObjectId, ref: 'City', so far so good.

If I query for a client and want also to filter by the 'province' property of City, I do this:

```js
const client = await Client
    .find({ name: "Gérard" })
    .populate([{
        path: 'city',
        model: City,
        match: { province: 'BA' }
    }]);
```

And the output is just fine:

```js
{
  "id": "627264e3ec261a883d42ead9",
  "name": "Gérard",
  "email": "gerard@depardieu.fr",
  "date": "1948-12-27",
  "active": true,
  "city": {
    "id": "627264e3ec261a883d42ead1",
    "name": "Buenos Aires",
    "province": "BA"
  }
}
```

Howerver, if I input a province code of a nonexistent city:

```js
const client = await Client
    .find({ name: "Gérard" })
    .populate([{
        path: 'city',
        model: City,
        match: { province: 'CA' }
    }]);
```

It would return me that:

```js
{
  "id": "627264e3ec261a883d42ead9",
  "name": "Gérard",
  "email": "gerard@depardieu.fr",
  "date": "1948-12-27",
  "active": true,
  "city": null
}
```

I don't want in this particular scenario, any instance of Client to be returned, and I don't know how to avoid this behavior with Mongoose, a behavior I never had to worry about with Spring Data for instance.

Any tips for me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain your question clearly, What exactly do you want?

Comment: @EhsanShavandi, I don't want a client to be returned if that client has a province different than the one I'm passing. For instance, client "name" = "Gérard", lives in a city which belongs to a proving named 'BA'. If I query for a city belonging to a province called 'CA', mongoose will return me client "name" = "Gérard" with property "city" = null. What I want, is for no client to be returned at all if that city doesn't exist. An example would be the analog SQL: SELECT * FROM CLIENT JOIN CITY ON CITY.ID=CLIENT.CITY_ID WHERE CITY.PROVINCE = 'CA' -- No client returned here, once province = 'BA'.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself, I had to go a little lower level with Mongoose and use aggregates and lookups.

```js
const client = await Client.aggregate([
  { 
    $match: { name: "Gérard" } 
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: City.collection.name,
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            province: 'BA'
          }
        }
      ], as: "city"
    }
  },
  {
     $unwind: "$city"
  },
  {
     $match: {
       city: { $ne: [] }
     }
   }
]);
```

Expected result:

```js
{
  "id": "627264e3ec261a883d42ead9",
  "name": "Gérard",
  "email": "gerard@depardieu.fr",
  "date": "1948-12-27",
  "active": true,
  "city": {
    "id": "627264e3ec261a883d42ead1",
    "name": "Buenos Aires",
    "province": "BA"
  }
}
```

Witch is ok, client name "Gérard" lives in "Buenos Aires", situated in province "BA".

On the other hand:

```js
const client = await Client.aggregate([
  { 
    $match: { name: "Gérard" } 
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: City.collection.name,
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            province: 'CA'
          }
        }
      ], as: "city"
    }
  },
  {
     $unwind: "$city"
  },
  {
     $match: {
       city: { $ne: [] }
     }
   }
]);
```

Returns nothing, once the city of "Buenos Aires" is not located in province "CA".

Notice here the last parameter (as an object) the array passed to Client.aggregate() receives:

```js
{
  $match: {
    city: { $ne: [] }
  }
}
```

This tells MongoDB that in order to return data city must be not equal to an empty array.

And with that the issue is solved.

Comment: That's a nice solution. I think the reason why you needed to use an aggregation query is because `.populate` predates `$lookup`. `clients.find().populate('city').limit(10)` would first query all `clients`, apply the `.limit(10)` and then a second query for the relevant `cities`. If it were to _then_ filter out nulls, you could end up with a result array of less than 10, which would be unexpected. (The [worse] alternative is to query _all_ clients with no limit, then query cities, _then_ limit)

Comment: @RickN, things became far easier to understand when I activated mongoose's debug mode, then I could really see what was been sent to MondoDB. With the code of my original question, several distinctive statements were been sent separately (and not in a transactional context) to the server, while when I finally started using aggregate, it all went to MongoDB as a single statement. You know, I come from a Java background, and Spring Data has always been so good to me, I didn't have to get my hands dirty as often as I have to do with Mongoose. But that's ok, that's the price of change.